# Flex Not Assigning Data to Variables

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am trying to assign a value from my database to a variable inside my Flex application. So far I read up a few ideas and I have at the moment the following code using a PHP web service:

```
protected function btnSubmitUser_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            username = txtUsername.text;
            password = txtPassword.text;
            serialno = txtSerialNo.text;
            userName.writeUTFBytes(username);
            passWord.writeUTFBytes(password);
            serialNo.writeUTFBytes(serialno);
            EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("Username", userName);
            EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("Password", passWord);
            EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("Serial", serialNo);
            getRepnameByUsernameResult2.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onMyResult); 
            getRepnameByUsernameResult2.token = repnameService.getRepnameByUsername(username);
        }

        protected function onMyResult(event:ResultEvent):void{ 
            repServ = getRepnameByUsernameResult2.lastResult as Repname; 
            repid = repServ.RepID; 
            RepID.writeInt(repid); 
            EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("Rep", RepID); 
            lblTestRep.text = RepID.toString();
        }
```

The label is a test label to see if the data is being assigned correctly. Unfortunately, I am getting errors with this where it declares:

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at views::SettingsView/onMyResult()[C:\Users\Justin\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Rep Aware\src\views\SettingsView.mxml:62]
```

This error is found at `repid = repServ.RepID;` of the above code.

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that `repServ` is `null`. So the property `lastResult` in:

```
repServ = getRepnameByUsernameResult2.lastResult as Repname;
```

is either `null`, or is not of type `Repname`.

The second option is possible because casting an object to an unrelated type using `as` returns `null`. The same cast would throw an exception if you do it like this:

```
repServ = Repname(getRepnameByUsernameResult2.lastResult);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I worked out that I had created my Return Type as a different object set and when I changed that return type back to Repname it worked.